# Pass state from a JSX NavBar to a JSX Map in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jsx, react-leaflet

So I can't figure out how to use React to pass the state of my navBar to my map. I get the date from my nav bar and I need to use it in my map to display stuff only if the date matches.

```
class NavSearchBar extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            startDate: moment().startOf('month'),
            endDate: moment().startOf('month'), 
    }//these get updated somewhere else in the code
    ...
```

and

```
class MyMap extends Component {
   OnEachCountry = (country, layer) => { // loops thru every country
        const country_name = country.properties.NAME; // name of country
        country.properties.reported_incidents = 0; // reported incidents
        for(var tweet2 = 0; tweet2<tweet_loc.length;tweet2++){ // loops thru tweet list
            var Location_Name = JSON.stringify(tweet_loc[tweet2].user.location);
            if(Location_Name.includes(country.properties.NAME) || 
               Location_Name.includes(country.properties.ADM0_A3)){ 
                country.properties.reported_incidents++;
              // in this for loop I want to check if its between the dates too so like 
              //nav.state.startDate
            }
        }
}
```

So I'm pretty new to React, Javascript, css, jsonfiles, just starting with this project. So where the loop is I want to grab something like Navbar.state.startDate, so I can compare it against the dates in my map file.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass states by props

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Welcome name="Sara" />
      <Welcome name="Cahal" />
      <Welcome name="Edite" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

There are the documentation oficial.
https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper

Comment: This helps me edit components later but doesn't send the date from one component to be used in another in real time or even in static time. Like I can pass the whole component and change something in the state before its rendered but I can't grab something from a form and use that in another component to display it. I want to grab a date from the user, and then based on that date render an element.

Comment: Wait Ill just make it render from my OnSubmit to create the following component, oh my god thank you

Comment: Exactly just use the props for everything communications between components, no problem that's the sense of stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Just make your whole website in one component then you don't need to pass anything.

Comment: That will get really hard to maintain.... just think about it. You want to crawl through a possible 1000+ lines of code?